# How to not appear on others' "Add friends to see what they're sharing" list on Google+

Tags: google-plus

As in the following:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOl4C.png]

Some people on there appear out of nowhere, ones I have contacted years ago once through my associated Gmail address. I'm assuming I'm appearing on their wall(?) as well.

Is there a setting that controls whether or not I want to be on such a "suggested contacts" list?

Answer (score 1):

There is just a possibility to untick the "Help others to find my profile in search". That hides your profile also from these lists.

Google Support on topic:
https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1151728?hl=en

Or remove those people from your Gmail "Other contacts".